# return key => value array pair with PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, amazon-web-services

So I've followed a few questions on here to try and get this to work....but I just can't seem to crack it. Essentially what i'm trying to do is loop through an XML file and return key => value pairs for elements from that file. For a bit more context, I'm trying to store an item's ASIN (Amazon API) as the key and it's image URL as the value in an array.

Here's the structure of the XML file, in case these helps someone determine where my code is flawed:

```
<Items>
<Request>
<IsValid>True</IsValid>
<ItemSearchRequest>
<Keywords>biology</Keywords>
<ResponseGroup>Images</ResponseGroup>
<SearchIndex>Books</SearchIndex>
</ItemSearchRequest>
</Request>
<TotalResults>280951</TotalResults>
<TotalPages>28096</TotalPages>
<MoreSearchResultsUrl>
http://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?camp=2025&creative=386001&location=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fgp%2Fsearch%3Fkeywords%3Dbiology%26url%3Dsearch-alias%253Dstripbooks&linkCode=xm2&tag=comparcom035-20&SubscriptionId=AKIAIQ7UEDX4CFRSBDXA
</MoreSearchResultsUrl>
<Item>
<ASIN>0321558235</ASIN>
<SmallImage>
<URL>
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41UWC4kbxGL._SL75_.jpg
</URL>
<Height Units="pixels">75</Height>
<Width Units="pixels">62</Width>
</SmallImage>
```

and here's the code I'm working with:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($SignedRequest);
$image = simplexml_load_file($getimage);



foreach ($image->Items->Item->ASIN as $key => $value) {
            $array[$key] = $image->Items->Item->SmallImage->URL;

        }

print_r($array);
```

My output looks like this:

```
Array ( [ASIN] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41UWC4kbxGL._SL75_.jpg ) )
```

I think I'm close.....but can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here? I can't seem to get my loop to assign the key and value properly without throwing some kind of error.

Answer (score 1):

You are close, you just need to cast the value as a string:

```
$array[$key] = (string) $image->Items->Item->SmallImage->URL;
```

Comment: yep, this works. although I had to cast both sides as a string, not just the right side. also had to change the $key variable to the full XML path to get it to work.
my problem now is my print_r only displays the first key value pair. There are about 10 ASINs in my XML file...any ideas why my loop isn't displaying everything?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$item = $image->Items->Item;
$array[(string)$item->ASIN] = (string)$item->SmallImage->URL;
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0321558235] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41UWC4kbxGL._SL75_.jpg            
)
```

Comment: casting both sides as a string is what i needed to do...thanks for this! My problem now is that my print_r isn't displaying the entire array....only the first key=>value pair. any ideas?